# Two values returning on @input in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using `updateRouter()` on @input in v-tabs. On clicking, in the updateRouter() i am printing the value of the current_tab in the console. If currently I am on tab *inforamtion* and then I click on *details* tab, thens it prints the values of previous tab twice. As below:

```
information
information
```

And since I am assigning the value of the current_tab to tabs, it doesnt work. Please help me find where I am going wrong.

```
<template>
  <v-layout row wrap>
    <v-flex xs12 sm12 lg12>
      <div>
        <v-tabs v-model="tabs" @input="updateRouter()">
          <v-tab href="#information">INFORMATION</v-tab>
          <v-tab href="#details">DETAILS</v-tab>
          <v-tab href="#services">SERVICES</v-tab>
          <v-tab-item value="#information" v-on:changes_event="alertMessage" v-on:changes_cancel="alertPhone" id="information">
            <Information />
          </v-tab-item>
          <v-tab-item value="#details" v-on:changes_event="alertMessage" v-on:changes_cancel="alertPhone" id="details">
            <Details />
          </v-tab-item>
          <v-tab-item value="#services" v-on:changes_event="alertMessage" v-on:changes_cancel="alertPhone" id="services">
            <Services />
          </v-tab-item>
        </v-tabs>
        <v-dialog v-model='editing'>
         <p>You have not saved. Please save</p>
         <v-btn @click.native='closeDialog'>Close</v-btn>
        </v-dialog>
      </div>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
import Information from 'views/information/edit.vue';
import Details from 'views/details/edit.vue';
import Services from 'views/services/edit.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    Information,
    Details,
    Services,
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      tabs: 'information',
      edit: false,
      current_tab: ''
      editing: false
    }
  },
  watch: {
    tabs(newVal, oldVal) {
      this.current_tab=oldVal;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closeDialog() {
     this.editing=false;
    },
    alertMessage() {
      this.edit = true;
    },
    alertPhone() {
      this.edit = false
    },
    updateRouter() {
      console.log(this.current_tab)
      this.tabs = this.current_tab
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Update 1

```
Removed @input="updateRouter()" from v-tabs

watch: {
 tabs(newVal, oldVal) {
  this.current_tab=oldVal;
  this.updateRouter()
 }
},
methods: {
 updateRouter() {
  console.log(this.current_tab)
  this.tabs_value = this.current_tab
 }
}
```

Update 2

```
updateRouter() {
 if(this.edit) {
  console.log(this.current_tab)
  this.tabs_value = this.current_tab
  this.editing = true
 }
}
```

Comment: place the this.updateRouter() in the watcher for `tabs` and obviously remove the @input from the dom

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Please check update 1 in the question. I did as you suggested but now I am getting this error

`You may have an infinite update loop in watcher with expression "tabs"`

Comment: sure its because your updating tabs again (though your update is now tabs_values). You may not need the watcher and you may not need updateRouter as code shown is kinda not doing anything. You have `v-model="tabs"` which should be enough as it will be reactive, if you need to fire off a method, do in watcher or fire it off in an @input like before but you dont need both.

Comment: and instead of the `id="information"`'s etc, use a `v-if="tab === 'information'"`, it seems like you trying to hook into the tabs change.. id do it all in vue with a model, presuming v-tabs exposes a model of which tab is active

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Based on the value of edit field, I want to prevent the switching between tabs. Something like, if edit is true, then this.tabs show be previous tab else switch to the next tab clicked.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Please check update 2, this is what I would have added eventually

Comment: @LawrenceCherone these tabs dont follow any steps. it is just user profile tabs with different user information under each tab. User can edit any time any tab. It is just that users shouldn't be able to change the tab when editing a form under a particular tab..

Comment: @LawrenceCherone if I use disabled then the tab title doesn't show at all. This is not what I want. I want to show the tab but when user clicks on another tab while editing the form on current tab the dialog box opens, prevents the user from changing the tab and user stays on the same tab.

Comment: i get ya, yeah is still not possible with current code (truthy values). You would need to look at the model of the form the user is editing if its changed/dirty from the original then apply your tab locking. I looked at the docs, the only options you have for preventing moving from tab to tab is `disabled`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone okay. Thankyou.